# SSME doesn't load from cache

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0

am using SSME for playing videos in my application...i have even used ISmoothStreamingCache interface to store the chunks in the cache...but when once the cache is done if i restart the playing video it doesn't pull the data from cache..instead send requests to the server...
can anybody help me on this...

namespace CacheDemo
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        ISO_StorageCache cache = null;
        double sliderProportion, mediaProportionSeconds;
        double sliderLengthSeconds;
        double conversion;
        TimeSpan tsPositionFromSlider = new TimeSpan();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SmoothPlayer.CurrentStateChanged +=
                    new RoutedEventHandler(SmoothPlayer_CurrentStateChanged);
            SmoothPlayer.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(SmoothPlayer_Loaded);
            SmoothPlayer.SmoothStreamingErrorOccurred +=
                new EventHandler(SmoothPlayer_SmoothStreamingErrorOccurred);
        }
        void SmoothPlayer_SmoothStreamingErrorOccurred(object sender, SmoothStreamingErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            OutputText.Text = e.ErrorMessage.ToString();
        }

```
    void SmoothPlayer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cache = new ISO_StorageCache();
        SmoothPlayer.SmoothStreamingSource = new Uri("http://<serverName>/media1.ism/Manifest");

       // SmoothPlayer.SmoothStreamingCache = cache;            
    }

    private void SliderBar_ValueChanged(object sender,
                   RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Calculate proportion of slider length at current position.
            sliderProportion = ((Slider)sender).Value / ((Slider)sender).Maximum;
            // Get media length in seconds.
            sliderLengthSeconds = SmoothPlayer.EndPosition.TotalSeconds;
            // Calculate position in seconds.
            conversion = sliderProportion * sliderLengthSeconds;
            // Convert seconds to a TimeSpan object.
            tsPositionFromSlider = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(conversion);
            // Assign new position by TimeSpan.
            SmoothPlayer.Position = tsPositionFromSlider;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OutputText.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    void SmoothPlayer_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (SmoothPlayer.CurrentState)
        {
            case SmoothStreamingMediaElementState.Playing:
                PlayButton.Content = "Pause";
                break;

            case SmoothStreamingMediaElementState.Paused:
                PlayButton.Content = "Play";
                break;

            case SmoothStreamingMediaElementState.Stopped:
                PlayButton.Content = "Play";
                break;
        }
    }

    private void SourceList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem item = ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);
        string selection = item.Content as string;

        switch (selection)
        {
            case "Lewis Clark clip":

                SmoothPlayer.SmoothStreamingSource = new Uri("http://<serverName>/media1.ism/Manifest");
                break;
            case "Media Two":
                SmoothPlayer.SmoothStreamingSource = null;
                //new Uri("http://<serverName>/media2.ism/Manifest");
                break;
            case "Media Three":
                SmoothPlayer.SmoothStreamingSource =
                    new Uri("http://<serverName>/media3.ism/Manifest");
                break;
            case "Media Four":
                SmoothPlayer.SmoothStreamingSource =
                    new Uri("http://<serverName>/media4.ism/Manifest");
                break;

        }
    }

    private void PlayButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (SmoothPlayer.AutoPlay)
        {
            case false:
                PlayButton.Content = "Play";
                break;
            case true:
                PlayButton.Content = "Pause";
                break;
        }
    }

    private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (SmoothPlayer.CurrentState)
        {
            case SmoothStreamingMediaElementState.Playing:
                SmoothPlayer.Pause();
                PlayButton.Content = "Play";
                break;

            case SmoothStreamingMediaElementState.Paused:
                SmoothPlayer.Play();
                PlayButton.Content = "Pause";
                break;

            case SmoothStreamingMediaElementState.Stopped:
                SmoothPlayer.Play();
                PlayButton.Content = "Pause";
                break;
        }
    }

    private void StopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SmoothPlayer.CurrentState == SmoothStreamingMediaElementState.Playing)
            SmoothPlayer.Stop();
        PlayButton.Content = "Play";
    }

    private void clearCacheButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cache.keyUrls.Clear();
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Clear();
        IsolatedStorageSettings.SiteSettings.Clear();

        IsolatedStorageFile isoFileArea = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        string[] names = isoFileArea.GetFileNames();

        foreach (string file in names)
        {
            isoFileArea.DeleteFile(file);
        }

    }

    private void increaseQuotaButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile isoFileArea = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        long availbleCacheBytes = isoFileArea.AvailableFreeSpace;
        long saveQuotaNumber = isoFileArea.Quota;

        isoFileArea.IncreaseQuotaTo(isoFileArea.Quota + 1048576);

        MessageBox.Show("New Quota: " + isoFileArea.Quota.ToString() +
            "\r\nPrevious Quota: " + saveQuotaNumber.ToString() +
            "\r\nAvailable Free Space: " + isoFileArea.AvailableFreeSpace.ToString(), "Cache Quota",
            MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }

    private void cacheOrNot_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ("Not Caching" == (string)cacheOrNot.Content)
        {
            SmoothPlayer.SmoothStreamingCache = cache;
            cacheOrNot.Content = "Caching On";
        }
        else if ("Caching On" == (string)cacheOrNot.Content)
        {
            SmoothPlayer.SmoothStreamingCache = null;
            cacheOrNot.Content = "Not Caching";
        }
    }

}
public class ISO_StorageCache : ISmoothStreamingCache
{
    // Dictionary to track URL/filename pairs of data in cache.
    public Dictionary<string, string> keyUrls = new Dictionary<string, string>(50);

    public ISO_StorageCache()
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile isoFileArea = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        foreach (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings)
        {
            if (!keyUrls.ContainsValue((string)pair.Value) && isoFileArea.FileExists((string)pair.Value))
                keyUrls.Add(pair.Key, ((string)pair.Value));
        }
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginPersist(CacheRequest request, CacheResponse response, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        state = false;
        CacheAsyncResult ar = new CacheAsyncResult();

        if (!keyUrls.ContainsKey(request.CanonicalUri.ToString()))
        {
            //state = true;
            ar.strUrl = request.CanonicalUri.ToString();
            ar.Complete(response, true);
            return ar;
        }

        ar.Complete(null, true);
        return ar;
    }

    public bool EndPersist(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

        if (((CacheAsyncResult)ar).Result != null)
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile isoFileArea = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            //const long NEEDED = 1024 * 1024 * 100;
            //isoFileArea.IncreaseQuotaTo(isoFileArea.Quota + NEEDED);
            if (((CacheResponse)(((CacheAsyncResult)ar).Result)).Response.Length < isoFileArea.AvailableFreeSpace)
            {
                string fileGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                if (!keyUrls.ContainsValue(fileGuid) && !keyUrls.ContainsKey(((CacheAsyncResult)ar).strUrl))
                {

                    IsolatedStorageFileStream isoFile = isoFileArea.CreateFile(fileGuid);

                    ((CacheResponse)(((CacheAsyncResult)ar).Result)).WriteTo(isoFile);
                    isoFile.Close();

                    keyUrls.Add(((CacheAsyncResult)ar).strUrl, fileGuid);
                    // Save key/value pairs for playback after application restarts.
                    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add(((CacheAsyncResult)ar).strUrl, fileGuid);
                    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginRetrieve(CacheRequest request, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        CacheResponse response = null;
        CacheAsyncResult ar = new CacheAsyncResult();
        ar.strUrl = request.CanonicalUri.ToString();
        ar.Complete(response, true);
        return ar;
    }

    public CacheResponse EndRetrieve(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

        CacheResponse response = null;

        if (keyUrls.ContainsKey(((CacheAsyncResult)ar).strUrl))
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile isoFileArea = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            string filename = keyUrls[((CacheAsyncResult)ar).strUrl];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) && isoFileArea.FileExists(filename))
            {
                IsolatedStorageFileStream stream =
                    isoFileArea.OpenFile(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
                response = new CacheResponse(stream);
            }
        }

        if (response != null)
            return response;
        else
            return response = new CacheResponse(0, null, null, null,
                System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Not Found", DateTime.Now);
    }
}

public class CacheAsyncResult : IAsyncResult
{
    public string strUrl { get; set; }

    public object AsyncState { get; private set; }

    public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle { get { return _completeEvent; } }

    public bool CompletedSynchronously { get; private set; }

    public bool IsCompleted { get; private set; }

    // Contains all the output result of the GetChunk API
    public Object Result { get; private set; }

    internal TimeSpan Timestamp { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Callback function when GetChunk is completed. Used in asynchronous mode only.
    /// Should be null for synchronous mode.
    /// </summary>
    private AsyncCallback _callback;

    /// <summary>
    /// Event is used to signal the completion of the operation
    /// </summary>
    private ManualResetEvent _completeEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the operation is completed
    /// </summary>
    public void Complete(Object result, bool completedSynchronously)
    {
        Result = result;
        CompletedSynchronously = completedSynchronously;

        IsCompleted = true;
        _completeEvent.Set();

        if (null != _callback) { ;  }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think your application implementation looks right. Basically, how ISmoothStreamingCache works is BeginRetrieve/EndRetrieve will be called to see whether your video is cached, if so retrieve it from the local cache. Otherwise, after getting video online, it will call BeginPersist and EndPersist to save your video into local storage.

Since you couldn't get video from cache, I suspect your cache may be full. Could you set a break point in Endpersist method and look for this line:
     if (((CacheResponse)(((CacheAsyncResult)ar).Result)).Response.Length <     isoFileArea.AvailableFreeSpace)

Meanwhile, try to clear cache in your browser. If you dont jump into this if block, you could increaseQuota also and try.

I have a blog regarding this topic and you could check it out. Hope it solves your problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mingfeis_code_block/archive/2012/04/10/smooth-streaming-cache-plug-in-implementation.aspx

Comment: Can you tell us what the blog entry says?